# where is boot parameters file stored in windows?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

Where is the file which holds the parameters for boot options (safe mode, etc) stored? I know that the BIOS software is stored in EEPROM. How about when we modify its parameters?

Say I have a computer that is stuck in the boot menu and I want to boot it in safe mode. How can I modify the boot parameters?

Comment: See this page....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/boot-options-in-windows

Comment: thanks for the link, what I understand is, when you modify the boot parameters they are stored in the bios chip, (?), so you can't alter one computer's boot options without being able to get into its boot options.

Comment: Not stored in the bios.